# Don't understand how to get the first line of the 2 strings

Tags: java

So i've been trying to find a way to get the first line of these 2 strings however I just don't know how and after testing doing .split(), .replace(), I still couldn't find a way to do it.

```java
    public static void readProxies() {
        boolean twix = true;
        if (twix) {
            try {
                File file = new File("proxies.txt");
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
                System.out.println("Using proxies!");

                BufferedReader Buff = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                String firstLine = Buff.readLine();
                System.out.println(firstLine.replace(":", "\n"));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // set proxies
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not using proxies.");
            assert true;
        }
    }
```

The textfile looks like the following abc:982
I want to only get *abc* however instead I got abc on 1 line and 123.0. on another.

Comment: `Buff.readLine();` you are reading 2 lines. call this method not once, but twice.

Comment: It's not 2 different lines in the textfile, in the textfile its 1 line which looks like this
abc:982
I made them into 2 lines using .replace(":", "\n") and that made it print out
abc
982
however they are still abc:982 in the textfile which is what I want, what I don't want is that I don't want it to print out 982, only abc. however I can't just do replace("982", "") because the value changes constantly therefore it wont work.

Comment: look at @Eirik Moseng and their answer

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it from your explanation and code, firstLine will contain for example "abc:982" after the call to Buff.readLine(), and you only want the abc part of the string. There are several ways to do this. You can for example use the String.split() method:

```
String[] str = firstLine.split(":");
```

If firstLine contains the data as specified above, str[0] will now contain abc and str[1] will contain 982. Hope this helps.